# How to use html template with vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I just want to try using `vue.js` but got into trouble when I try to use a template that I bought. I've put all the `.css` and `.js` files into index.html and then call the components inside `vue.js` itself.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
    <meta content="Preview page of Metronic Admin Theme #1 for statistics, charts, recent events and reports"
          name="description"/>
    <meta content="" name="author"/>

    <title>My Application</title>

    <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"/>
    <link href="assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <link href="assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"/>
    <link href="assets/global/plugins/morris/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="assets/global/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/jqvmap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL STYLES -->
    <link href="assets/global/css/components-md.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style_components" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="assets/global/css/plugins-md.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- END THEME GLOBAL STYLES -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME LAYOUT STYLES -->
    <link href="assets/layouts/layout/css/layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="assets/layouts/layout/css/themes/darkblue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color"/>
    <link href="assets/layouts/layout/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- END THEME LAYOUT STYLES -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="src/assets/logo.png"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css">

    <!-- BEGIN CORE PLUGINS -->
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/js.cookie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/morris/morris.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/morris/raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/counterup/jquery.waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/counterup/jquery.counterup.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/pie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/radar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/themes/light.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/themes/patterns.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/themes/chalk.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/amcharts/ammap/ammap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/amcharts/ammap/maps/js/worldLow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amstockcharts/amstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/horizontal-timeline/horizontal-timeline.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.categories.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/jquery-easypiechart/jquery.easypiechart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/jquery.sparkline.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.russia.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.europe.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.germany.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.usa.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/data/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="assets/global/scripts/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="assets/pages/scripts/dashboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME LAYOUT SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="assets/layouts/layout/scripts/layout.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/layouts/layout/scripts/demo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/layouts/global/scripts/quick-sidebar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/layouts/global/scripts/quick-nav.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END THEME LAYOUT SCRIPTS -->
</head>


</head>
<body class="page-header-fixed page-sidebar-closed-hide-logo page-content-white page-md">

    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All pages are running perfectly and successfully called by  belongs `vue.js` but **does not appear** if I use the calling page with `<router-link>`

**Graph.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 class="page-title"> Grafik Pages
            <small>statistics, charts, recent events and reports</small>
        </h1>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <!-- BEGIN PORTLET-->
                <div class="portlet light bordered">
                    <div class="portlet-title">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <i class="icon-bar-chart font-dark hide"></i>
                            <span class="caption-subject font-dark bold uppercase">Site Visits</span>
                            <span class="caption-helper">weekly stats...</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-devided" data-toggle="buttons">
                                <label class="btn red btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm active">
                                    <input name="options" class="toggle" id="option1" type="radio">New</label>
                                <label class="btn red btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm">
                                    <input name="options" class="toggle" id="option2" type="radio">Returning</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body">

                        <div id="site_statistics_loading" style="display: none;">
                            <img src="../../../assets/global/img/loading.gif" alt="loading"> </div>
                        <div id="site_statistics_content" class="display-none" style="display: block;">
                            <div id="site_statistics" class="chart" style="padding: 0px; position: relative;"> <canvas class="flot-base" style="direction: ltr; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 438px; height: 300px;" width="657" height="450"></canvas><div class="flot-text" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; font-size: smaller; color: rgb(84, 84, 84);"><div class="flot-x-axis flot-x1-axis xAxis x1Axis" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; display: block;"><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 48px; top: 285px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 10px; text-align: center;">02/2013</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 48px; top: 285px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 58px; text-align: center;">03/2013</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 48px; top: 285px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 107px; text-align: center;">04/2013</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 48px; top: 285px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 155px; text-align: center;">05/2013</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 48px; top: 285px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 203px; text-align: center;">06/2013</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 48px; top: 285px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 251px; text-align: center;">07/2013</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 48px; top: 285px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 300px; text-align: center;">08/2013</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 48px; top: 285px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 348px; text-align: center;">09/2013</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 48px; top: 285px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 396px; text-align: center;">10/2013</div></div><div class="flot-y-axis flot-y1-axis yAxis y1Axis" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; display: block;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 273px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 20px; text-align: right;">0</div><div style="position: absolute; top: 220px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 1px; text-align: right;">1000</div><div style="position: absolute; top: 166px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 1px; text-align: right;">2000</div><div style="position: absolute; top: 113px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 1px; text-align: right;">3000</div><div style="position: absolute; top: 59px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 1px; text-align: right;">4000</div><div style="position: absolute; top: 6px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 1px; text-align: right;">5000</div></div></div><canvas class="flot-overlay" style="direction: ltr; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 438px; height: 300px;" width="657" height="450"></canvas></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END PORTLET-->
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <!-- BEGIN PORTLET-->
                <div class="portlet light bordered">
                    <div class="portlet-title">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <i class="icon-share font-red-sunglo hide"></i>
                            <span class="caption-subject font-dark bold uppercase">Revenue</span>
                            <span class="caption-helper">monthly stats...</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <a href="" class="btn dark btn-outline btn-circle btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true"> Filter Range
                                    <span class="fa fa-angle-down"> </span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="javascript:;"> Q1 2014
                                            <span class="label label-sm label-default"> past </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="javascript:;"> Q2 2014
                                            <span class="label label-sm label-default"> past </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="active">
                                        <a href="javascript:;"> Q3 2014
                                            <span class="label label-sm label-success"> current </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="javascript:;"> Q4 2014
                                            <span class="label label-sm label-warning"> upcoming </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body">
                        <div id="site_activities_loading" style="display: none;">
                            <img src="../../../assets/global/img/loading.gif" alt="loading"> </div>
                        <div id="site_activities_content" class="display-none" style="display: block;">
                            <div id="site_activities" style="height: 228px; padding: 0px; position: relative;"> <canvas class="flot-base" style="direction: ltr; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 438px; height: 228px;" width="657" height="342"></canvas><div class="flot-text" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; font-size: smaller; color: rgb(84, 84, 84);"><div class="flot-x-axis flot-x1-axis xAxis x1Axis" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; display: block;"><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 43px; top: 209px; font: small-caps 400 11px/18px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 21px; text-align: center;">DEC</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 43px; top: 209px; font: small-caps 400 11px/18px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 66px; text-align: center;">JAN</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 43px; top: 209px; font: small-caps 400 11px/18px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 109px; text-align: center;">FEB</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 43px; top: 209px; font: small-caps 400 11px/18px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 151px; text-align: center;">MAR</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 43px; top: 209px; font: small-caps 400 11px/18px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 197px; text-align: center;">APR</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 43px; top: 209px; font: small-caps 400 11px/18px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 239px; text-align: center;">MAY</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 43px; top: 209px; font: small-caps 400 11px/18px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 285px; text-align: center;">JUN</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 43px; top: 209px; font: small-caps 400 11px/18px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 330px; text-align: center;">JUL</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 43px; top: 209px; font: small-caps 400 11px/18px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 371px; text-align: center;">AUG</div><div style="position: absolute; max-width: 43px; top: 209px; font: small-caps 400 11px/18px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 417px; text-align: center;">SEP</div></div><div class="flot-y-axis flot-y1-axis yAxis y1Axis" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; display: block;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 197px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 20px; text-align: right;">0</div><div style="position: absolute; top: 149px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 7px; text-align: right;">500</div><div style="position: absolute; top: 100px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 1px; text-align: right;">1000</div><div style="position: absolute; top: 52px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 1px; text-align: right;">1500</div><div style="position: absolute; top: 3px; font: small-caps 400 11px/14px &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif; color: rgb(111, 123, 138); left: 1px; text-align: right;">2000</div></div></div><canvas class="flot-overlay" style="direction: ltr; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 438px; height: 228px;" width="657" height="342"></canvas></div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin: 20px 0 10px 30px">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-stat">
                                    <span class="label label-sm label-success"> Revenue: </span>
                                    <h3>$13,234</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-stat">
                                    <span class="label label-sm label-info"> Tax: </span>
                                    <h3>$134,900</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-stat">
                                    <span class="label label-sm label-danger"> Shipment: </span>
                                    <h3>$1,134</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-stat">
                                    <span class="label label-sm label-warning"> Orders: </span>
                                    <h3>235090</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END PORTLET-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</template>

<script>
    export default {
        created () {

        },
        methods: {

        }
    }
</script>
```

But when I refresh the page (manual), the chart data to come up with the perfect.

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <navbar></navbar>
        <div class="page-container">
            <leftmenu></leftmenu>
            <container></container>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import Menu from './components/Menu.vue'
import LeftMenu from './components/Leftmenu.vue'
import Container from './components/Container.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        'navbar': Menu,
        'leftmenu': LeftMenu,
        'container': Container,
    }
}

</script>
```

routes.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/",
            component: require('./components/pages/Home.vue'),
            meta: {
                forVisitors: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/home",
            component: require('./components/pages/Home.vue'),
            meta: {
                forVisitors: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/graph",
            component: require('./components/pages/Graph.vue'),
            meta: {
                forVisitors: true
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/form",
            component: require('./components/pages/Form.vue'),
            meta: {
                forVisitors: true
            }
        }
    ],
    linkActiveClass: 'nav-item start active open',
    mode: 'history'
})

export default router
```

[image: 1]

What I miss??

Thanks

Comment: All bunch of code you posted is mostly useless for us.We need more VueJS related code - current one doesn't tell us anything special.

Comment: Hi @BelminBedak please check my code update

Comment: Thanks this is better.Have you configured your server for history mode usage ? https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: Yes...My config is `mode: 'history'`

Comment: I see that, my question was related to server configuration - because when you are using the HTML5 History mode your server (Apache, nginx, Node or something else) need special configuration that is pretty well described on link I posted.
Also could you show us how you deal with `<router-link>`
Btw any console error ?

Comment: No error when I see.. Only `WebSocket connection` because my office using proxy (maybe). I just switched from mode: history using `#` but no effect.

You can see my console : https://ibb.co/eE3Hdv

Comment: My routes.js code is above. And my code to call link is : http://pastebin.com/pz0Y5wwi

Comment: Hm so far, as I can see, everything looks normal.If you are allowed to share repo that would be much easier to detect the problem...
And how you init your Vue instance - `new Vue({...})` I mean on this part of code.

Comment: Wait..I will create my code in github for you now

Comment: I upload with my google drive coz I lost my github password. Please check my full code here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByvY_8Sr-qf7UEJMSEk0M3Q0N0E

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137539/discussion-between-belmin-bedak-and-bertho-joris).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the repo, I noticed bunch of jQuery data that sometimes could mess with VueJS.

The initialization of the jQuery graph into `Graph.vue` component, should be done in some of lifecylce methods when document is ready

```
mounted() {
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // chart init method
  })
}
```

I still suggest to not mix up jQuery and Vue a lot - they are conceptually different and It just make a big mess.

Comment: Thanks @Belmin for your help